# How to get full Url from a Html Helper Class that I made?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an html helper library that I am making and one of my plugins needs urls to be passed in. I don't want to pass in the full url since they every-time I change something around I have to go and fix all of the urls up.

How can I get a full Url path in my file? Like if I pass in a relative path or something it gets resolved to a full path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VirtualPathUtility might be a place to look. For example using

```
VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(src);
```

will render paths like "~/App/test.jpg" to an absolute location e.g "/VirtualDirectory/App/test.jpg" as well as relative paths. The methods exposed on an instance of the UrlHelper (e.g. Content) class might also be of help.

Answer (score 1):

For future visitors to this thread I use the following code frequently

```
var baseUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.LocalPath != "/")
    baseUrl = baseUrl.Replace(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.LocalPath.Substring(1), "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(string)

Comment: HttpCurrent does not show up for me. I have the System.Web namespace in my file.

Comment: Ah it is "HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath"

Comment: Sorry I guess I should have mentioned this url is used for a picture that I want to display. This gets the whole path but it gets it to my hard drive so it seems not to display.